# defining object types in open graph for facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wish to develop an application(facebook) which can publish the current actions of user on my website to his timeline.

Currently , I am able to post updates , but they are not dynamic. I mean I am unable to post the exact price and product name as searched by our user.

I will explain a bit through an example pic[image]

I have set two custom properties Product:prodname and Product:price thinking that it will help me in sending the actual product user has searched and the price of the result he had obtained.

Now, I wish the preview to accept 2 variables prodname and price.

Am I on the right path ? Because facebook is not accepting the singular noun I submitted !

Please suggest and comment, if I am unclear in my question !!

Comment: What was the message returned when Facebook denied the noun

Comment: You aren't allowed to use those characters in your action text. Only [a-z-,'"& ]. You wrote

prodname and obtained a deal at Rs price

Comment: Plz dont close, if u dont have answer to this. I am really strugguling with this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem. The mistake I was doing was that I was setting custom properties to the product(object). However, actually, we need to add custom properties to the compare(action) instead. Finally we need to send the value of the custom properties to the open graph. Just concat it with the open graph url.

Here is a pic explaining the same :-

[image]

Snapshot of the page defining the object :-

[image]

Snapshot of the part defining the object preview:-

[image]

and then the final desired result :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Open Graph supports adding custom properties like that.

You should edit the Preview object to fill out the data or using an existing Product object url.

Comment: But various websites post users score etc on their walls ! How is that done ? I think I am wrong somewhere !

Comment: @PrashantSingh Those are games. Your app is not a game, yet I don't think there is anything different in the settings. It would best to provide a screenshot supporting your observation.

Comment: I will find out a solution and will be back to u soon. I know its POSSIBLE, just not clicking :D